# SQL JOIN 3 TABLES WITH COUNT AND GROUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I Have 3 tables like that:

```
EXPEDITION (ID, CreateDate, Status);
PACKAGE (ID, EXPEDITION_ID)
ITEM (ID, EXPEDIITONPACKAGE_ID);
```

I need to know, for each expedition, the quantity of packages and the quantity of items.

Comment: So you have all the things to get started. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to write a query to get this?  You should really include your attempts at solving it.  Plus it would be really helpful if you included some sample data and the final desired result.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet?  This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Yes i tried but i m getting the same values in the COUNT(T2.ID2) and COUNT(T3.ID3);

Comment: Do you possibly want to count the **distinct** values in those two columns?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This is the query that seems to have it.

```
    SELECT 
        E.ID, 
        P.Packages, 
        I.Items 
    FROM EXPEDITION E

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT E.ID, COUNT(P.ID) AS "Packages" FROM EXPEDITION E
        LEFT JOIN PACKAGE P
        ON E.ID = P.EXPEDITION_ID
        GROUP BY E.ID
    ) P
    ON E.ID = P.ID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT P.ID as "PackageID", COUNT(I.ID) AS "Items" FROM PACKAGE P
        JOIN ITEM I
        ON P.ID = I.EXPEDIITONPACKAGE_ID
        GROUP BY P.ID
    ) I
    ON P.ID = I.PackageId

    GROUP BY 
        E.ID, 
        P.Packages, 
        I.Items

    ORDER BY 
        E.ID
```

It has two inner queries, that count the IDs separately, and they are joined in the main query to show the results.

Comment: Thats the solution i've tryed in first place, but but is not working in that case the value of COUNT(T2.ID2) and COUNT(T3.ID3) have always the same value

Comment: What did you expect then? There are no `outer joins`, so the number of rows on the first side of the join will always be the same as the right side.

Comment: @André The join which is posted is a inner join. This will match each record ID which appears in all tables, hence the numbers are the same. From your response you might want to research left,right and outer joins

Comment: @André - here's the updated version, see if it works for you. It did for me. Would do a fiddle, but sqlfiddle is not quite right at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not tested yet...but it should work..
;With c1 as 
(
Select e.expid, count(e.expid) as qtyPck
From packages p inner join 
Expeditions e on p.expid = e.expid
Group by e.expid
),
C2 as
(
Select i.pakId, count(i.pakId) as qtyItems
From items i inner join packages p
On i.pakId = p.pakId
Group by i.pakid
)
Select e.expId, p.qtyPck, I.qtyItems
From expeditions e
Join packages p on p.expId = e.expId
Join items i on i.pakId = p.pakId;