# count and group by in hierarchy of 3 tables with nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a hierarchy of 3 tables.

I need a query that returns all entries from the top table and counts for entries in the bottom of this hierarchy.

Example:

```
table paragraph has columns : id_paragraph
table sentence has columns  : id_sentence, id_paragraph
table word has columns      : id_word, id_sentence, font, color
```

Example Output:

```
id_paragraph, sentence_count, word_count, word_count_no_font, word_count_font_present, word_count_no_color, word_count_color_present
1, 10, 100, 20, 80, 25, 75
2, 20, 200, 40, 160, 50, 150
```

Explanation of the first row:
id_paragraph = 1,  has 10 sentences,  sum of words in these sentence = 100, sum of words in these sentence in this paragraph where the font is empty = 20,  sum of words in these sentence in this paragraph where the font is not empty = 80, sum of words in these sentence in this paragraph where the color is empty = 25,  sum of words in these sentence in this paragraph where the color is not empty = 75.

I see how "left join" and "group by"  give me a solution of a hierarchy of 2 deep.  I tried twisting [SQL JOIN 3 TABLES WITH COUNT AND GROUP BY CLAUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551919/sql-join-3-tables-with-count-and-group-by-clause), but obviously, I don't get something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `count(distinct)`:

```
select s.id_paragraph,
       count(distinct s.id_sentence) as num_sentences,
       count(*) as num_words,
       count(w.font) as num_words_with_font,
       sum(w.font is null) as num_words_without_font,
       count(w.color) as num_words_with_color,
       sum(w.color is null) as num_words_without_color
from sentence s join
     word w
     on w.id_sentence = s.id_word
group by s.id_paragraph;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id_paragraph,
(SELECT COUNT(s.id_sentence) FROM sentence s WHERE p.id_paragraph = s.id_paragraph) sentence_count,
(SELECT COUNT(w.id_word) FROM sentence s, word w WHERE s.id_sentence = w.id_sentence AND p.id_paragraph = s.id_paragraph) word_count,
(SELECT COUNT(IFNULL(w.font, 1)) FROM sentence s, word w WHERE s.id_sentence = w.id_sentence AND p.id_paragraph = s.id_paragraph AND w.font IS NULL) word_count_no_font,
(SELECT COUNT(w.font) FROM sentence s, word w WHERE s.id_sentence = w.id_sentence AND p.id_paragraph = s.id_paragraph AND w.font IS NOT NULL) word_count_font_present
...
FROM paragraph p
;
```